# how to access iphone system preferences

Tags: iphone

How can I access (read) the "global preferences" in an iPhone application.

Idea: my application provides "keyboard clicks" - I want to enable / disable them depening on what the users has set on his iPhone settings.

But I have no idea how to read those settings (also the "mute switch" status would be interesting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the mute switch see here. http://www.restoroot.com/Blog/2008/12/25/audiosessioninitialize-workarounds/

Essentially you are just need this.

```
// "Ambient" makes it respect the mute switch
    // Must call this once to init session
    if (!gAudioSessionInited)
    {
        AudioSessionInterruptionListener    inInterruptionListener = NULL;
        OSStatus    error;
        if ((error = AudioSessionInitialize (NULL, NULL, inInterruptionListener, NULL)))
        {
            NSLog(@"*** Error *** GBMusicTrack - initWithPath: error in AudioSessionInitialize: %d.", error);
        }
        else
        {
            gAudioSessionInited = YES;
        }
    }

    SInt32  ambient = kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound;
    if (AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (ambient), &ambient))
    {
        NSLog(@"*** Error *** GBMusicTrack - initWithPath: could not set Session property to ambient.");
    }
```

As for reading system preferences, you can't at least not through public API's!

Comment: Thanks Lee.

Bitter news - on the one hand apple says (in UI... topic: what a user expects)...

And on the other hand they give no access to those settings which are important in "what a user expectes".

In my situation - sounds for my keyboard can't depend on what the user set's globally.

"Animation Sounds" can not depend on the "silent switch".

I use monotouch which means "audio session not fully supported", and further I don't use audio sessions - I just use PlaySystemSound

Comment: I think as long as you honour the mute switch setting you will be fine.

Comment: my problem to honor the mute switch - monotouch doesn't offer access to the AudioSession (or at least not complete). I learned this when I tried to implement "background audio should duck"

Comment: one last thing - I gave you link a closer look -- but couldn't find anything about the mute switch there...